# Meaning of “Anstrengungen geben”

Tags: meaning

„Der Kampf gegen die Miliz müsse von der internationalen Gemeinschaft getragen werden. Es muss eine gemeinsame ***Anstrengung geben***, den Krebs zu entfernen, damit er sich nicht ausbreitet.“ (via [Spiegel Online](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/us-militaer-in-syrien-geiselbefreiung-gescheitert-a-987233.html))

Is `Antrengungen geben` the same as `Anstrengungen machen` ? When I looked it up in all the dictionaries online the phrase `Anstrengungen machen` kept coming up. Is it also an alternative for `sich bemühen` and `sich Mühe machen`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase is not "Anstrengung geben". "geben" is just the verb in "es muss etwas geben" in the meaning of "there must something happen". The thing that should happen is "eine gemeinsame Anstrengung".

Comment: +1. More generically, "es gibt" is often translated as "there is".

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... and with an added oblogation "there has/have to be"